# virtualenv venv --python=python3.7 returns command not found in console

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to create a virtual environment by executing this command:
virtualenv venv --python=python3.7 but it returns 'command not found' error

Comment: have you not installed [`virtualenv`](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/#lower-level-virtualenv) yet?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+command+not+found

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think `virtualenv` is deprecated now that `venv` comes with Python 3.7 (https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Virtual environments are created like so with `venv` (according to the docs):

```
    python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

I don't think `venv` is a `virtualenv` command (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#usage; https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments), and at least not for what you are trying to do. The command for new virtual environments with `virtualenv` is `virtualenv ENV`.

Comment: If you're a Mac user then `venv` will also set up Python as a framework. This makes Matplotlib's default renderer work. I've switched to `venv` just for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should install virtualenv first:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

maybe you should check the virtualenvwrapper, which is based on virtualenv and much easier to manage your virtual environment.

Comment: hi, yes I have installed it already